# How to convert KML to shapefile in ArcMap 9.3.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, kml, arcgis-9.3

I would like to know about conversion tools available  for KML to shapefile formats. In ArcMap 9.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know if ArcMap 9.3.1 has the tool. But there is a Tool called "KML to Layer". You need tho export the temporary layer to shp.

If not use this online conversion:
http://www.zonums.com/online/kml2shp.php

Answer (score 0):

In the Online Help for ArcGIS 9.3.1 there is a page that discusses its [KML support](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An%20overview%20of%20KML%20support%20in%20ArcGIS):

> Importing KML into the geodatabase for use in ArcMap, ArcGlobe or
>   ArcScene See the [Data Interoperability Extension](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_Data_Interoperability). Alternatively,
>   see how the user community is supporting KML by reviewing [live search
>   results for KML in ArcScripts](http://arcscripts.esri.com/scripts.asp?pg=1&sb=1&ob=asc&eDate=&n=&top=&eLang=&eProd=&perPage=10&eQuery=kml)